# Search address on Google Map v3 by pressing ENTER

Tags: google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have working java script Google Map Api v3 with Geocoding. 
When I type for example post code in search box I can select address from list. If I will do same thing and press ENTER nothing is happening. How to modify code?

```
<input id="address" type="textbox">
```

Java script code:

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

function initialize(){
  //MAP
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.469186, -0.361166);
  var options = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  //GEOCODER
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: false
  });

  //CIRCLE
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.469186, -0.361166),
    fillColor: '#204617',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeColor: '#6DE953',
    strokeOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  circle.setRadius(10000);
}

$(document).ready(function() { 

  initialize();

  $(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
      }
    });
    document.getElementById("address").focus();
  });
});
```

I have try adding search button:

```
<input id="search" type="button" value="Search" onclick="codeAddress()">
```

and adding function `codeAddress()` to Java Script but I must have done something wrong as that didn't worked.

Working (without ENTER) [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sGB96/8/)

Comment: I'm not seeing your codeAddress function in the code you've provided, which is going to be where the issue lies.  In the same way that you're providing an event handler to the on click event, you will need to do the same thing for the enter event.

Comment: I have changed `$(function() {` to `function codeAddress(){` but that broke code and nothing worked so I reverted that change.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this maybe you'll get some ideas. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

they are also using geocode, so you can refer the code.

Comment: That code doesn't work with enter. You have to select address from the list.

Comment: One one thing you can do call the method on onkeypress() jquery,and check the keycode of the pressed key if the keycode = 32(enter) then perform the search

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% certain what you are doing wrong, since you did not post all the code. But this example works (I tested in FF):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>    <!-- Google Maps API -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script>
    var geocoder;
var map;
var marker;

function initialize(){
  //MAP
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(51.469186, -0.361166);
  var options = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), options);

  //GEOCODER
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: false
  });

  //CIRCLE
  var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
    map: map,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.469186, -0.361166),
    fillColor: '#204617',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    strokeColor: '#6DE953',
    strokeOpacity: 0.4,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  circle.setRadius(10000);
}
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() { 

  initialize();

  $(function() {
    $("#address").autocomplete({
      //This bit uses the geocoder to fetch address values
      source: function(request, response) {
        geocoder.geocode( {'address': request.term }, function(results, status) {
          response($.map(results, function(item) {
            return {
              label:  item.formatted_address,
              value: item.formatted_address,
              latitude: item.geometry.location.lat(),
              longitude: item.geometry.location.lng()
            }
          }));
        })
      },
      //This bit is executed upon selection of an address
      select: function(event, ui) {
        var location = new google.maps.LatLng(ui.item.latitude, ui.item.longitude);
        marker.setPosition(location);
        map.setCenter(location);
      }
    });
    document.getElementById("address").focus();
  });
});


    </script>
    <style>
    /* style settings for Google map */
    #map_canvas
    {
        width : 500px;  /* map width */
        height: 500px;  /* map height */
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()"> 
    <!-- Dislay Google map here -->
    <div id='map_canvas' ></div>
    <input id="address" type="textbox">
</body>
</html>
```